# How can I add Items to an array of a class type, dynamically in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a code snippet similar to this

```
class Student{
var id: Int
var name: String
var mark: Int
}

class Fetch{
init(count:Int){
   var student=[Student]()
}}
```

I want to add details of students(id , name and mark) of 'count' number of students

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do here? “Add details”, do you mean to create new objects or editing existing ones?  Where does the data, the details, com from that you want to add?

Comment: Your first mistake is to define your variable student in the initializer. When defined inside the initializer is it a local variable of the initializer, and goes away when the init method returns. You need to move the definition of `student` outside of the init and into the class as in Владимир's answer (I'd also suggest calling an array of `Student` objects the plural, `students`.)

Comment: Adding Items mean, I want to add the above three details(id,name,mark) of 5 Students

Answer (score 0):

in playground

```
struct Student{
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var mark: Int
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, mark: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.mark = mark
    }
}

class Fetch{
    var students = [Student]()
    
    init(count:Int){
        students = []
        for i in 0..<count {
            let s = Student(id: i + 1, name: "Student\(i+1)", mark: (i % 5) + 1)
            students.append(s)
        }
    }
}

let sc = Fetch(count: 4)
print(sc.students)
```

[image]